Sharing configuration between classess in the different packeges in Java
Let's assume that I have 3 classes: JSONReader, Configuration, Worker.
With JSONReader I setting up the fields of Configuration.
With Worker I getting data of fields from Configuration.
So here the example of reader...
public class JSONReader {
    //Read json file and it's data...
    Configuration config = Configuration.getInstance();
    config.getInstance().setURISource(reader.get("uriSource"));
}

Here's my configuration class
public class Configuration{
    private Configuration(){}
    private static Configuration instance = null;

    private final String uriSource;

    public static synchronized Configuration getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Configuration();

        return instance;
    }

    public String setURISource(String uri){
        this.uriSource = uri;
    }

    public String getURISource(){
        return uriSource;
    }
}

Here the worker...
public class Worker {
    \\Doing some stuff, at certain point I need to get the data..
Connection connection = new Connection();    
connection.setConnection(Configuration.getInstance().getURISource()/*and other data*/);
}

I used the approach of singleton, verified the hashcode getting an instance of Configuration in my reader and worker...hashcodes returns the same value.
But, getters are null the same as variables are null after being set them in my reader.
Any suggestions? Ideas?

You can’t have a final field and a setter writing to the same field. This code will not pass the compiler. It also points to the problem of your actual code: the idea of having a final field is correct, as the singleton can only work correctly in that case. However, having a setter contradicts this idea. Either, the setter in your real life code does not actually write to the field or the field is not final. In either case, it’s broken. In the latter case, there is no guarantee that setURISource(…) has been invoked before getURISource() and also, the data exchange is not thread safe.

That's because you are calling getInstance() twice.
config.getInstance().setURISource(reader.get("uriSource"));

Instead, you can directly do this:
config.setURISource(reader.get("uriSource"));

Also, variables mustn't be final if you want to set them later.

That’s nonsense. The object is a singleton; it doesn’t matter how often you invoke Configuration.getInstance(), it will always return the same object. Granted, since the posted code doesn’t compile, there might be other differences in the real code, but a solution based on guesswork about what is not shown in the question is not helpful to any future reader.
